# Get nth item from observable array

Tags: arrays, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray

I'm learning Knockout, and have an `pdfs` observable array which consists of 4 items. I need the HTML output of the items to look like this:

```
Intro Text
[Item 1].name is located in [Item 1].location

Some links, other body text
[Item 2].name is located in [Item 2].location
[Item 3].name is located in [Item 3].location
[Item 4].name is located in [Item 4].location
```

I've found a few places that reference `data-bind="text: pdfs[nth].name"` but if I do this I get 'pdfs is not defined' or similar. I realise I could use two foreach loops and the `<!-- ko if: $index() == nth -->` but surely there has to be a better way?

It seems like something a few people would want to do, so I hope theres a robust solution. I realise I'm talking about the first item here (and everything else could just be looped out in the `foreach`), but I'm interested overall for `nth` (if I want to put say, item 3 somewhere special).

*I don't really want to create a custom binding, if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `data-bind="text: pdfs()[nth].name"`?

Take a look at "Reading information from an observableArray" on this page: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html. If `pdfs` is an observable array, then to get the underlying array (so that you can index into it using []), you need to call the function. Thus, the ().